# react-native webview has background video

Tags: ios, react-native, video, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview.  The webpage i am showing has a background video that plays on loop.

It works perfectly on android but on IOS it doesnt play at all.

If i change the prop:

```
mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
```

then as the webpage opens it opens the video into a media player, this is also obviously not a solution.

I have tried all other props with no success including

allowsFullscreenVideo
scalesPageToFit
allowsInlineMediaPlayback

Comment: Does the web page background video, play in iOS safari out off your app? I want to know whether it's web page issue or rn-webview?

Comment: Can you please share the URL with background video playback? So that I test it and maybe could help to find a workaround